# How to modify regex so that it does and doesn't match certain numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I modify this regex so that 0 isn't matched, but the number like 15.0 is?  See: http://rubular.com/r/8OMVYh0SBw.  I can't quite figure it out.  Regex is my Achilles heel.

```
^[+-]?(?:(?!0)\d{1,2}|0)(?:\.5)?$
```

FYI - everything above the dashed line is supposed to be matched, and anything below shouldn't be matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works perfectly for me.

### [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/axttoVDIlQ)

```
^[+-]?(?:[1-9]\d?)(?:\.\d)?$
```

---

For the future, the following two are equivalent, but the latter is more efficient.

```
(?!0)\d{1,2}    
[1-9]\d?
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.  In the two I said were equivalent, the second wouldn't match 10, or any other number that ends in a 0.  It's fixed now (see edit for original).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
^[+-]?(?!0+(?:\.0)?$|0)\d{1,2}(?:\.\d)?$
```